# Navigation bar with vertically centered elements

Tags: html, css, navigation, vertical-alignment

I've been trying to create a navigation bar that meets the following criteria:

1. Spans 15% height.
2. Spans 100% width.
3. Navigation bar is aligned to the top of the site.
4. Elements within the navigation bar are vertically centered within it.
5. The last menu option is aligned to the far right of the navigation bar.

I've been playing with `<div>` and `<ul>` to implement the elements. I've spent a lot of time on it and researched it. I can't seem to find a way to vertically center the elements, which are images, if I use a percentage height. I assume this issue is because the `<header>` and `<nav>` elements are block elements, as is the div element, being that "vertical-align" only works on inline elements.

Questions, for those wise enough to provide what are probably easy answers:

1. Can I use "vertical-align" on block elements if I override the "display" element to the "inline" value? It seems like the answer is negative.
2. Can I right-align one `<li>` within a `<ul>` while the other `<li>` are left-aligned?
3. The only way I can get it to work is to use fixed height values on the navigation bar as well as padding around the elements. Is that my only option or does anyone know of a way I can make it work with a percentage height?

Basic code to express what I'd like to do (assuming all the `<html>` and other foundational tags are there, too; and I am aware the code below doesn't work but it shows the basic idea):

```
<style>
html, body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.menu_bar {
display: inline; /* This element seems to mess things up pretty bad so I assume I can't do it       
that way. I was only using it so my <ul> would be within an inline element which would allow me 
to use vertical-align. */
height: 15%;
width: 100%;
background-color: #000000;
}

.menu_items {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.menu_logo {
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: left;
}

.menu_option1 {
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: left;
}

.menu_option2 {
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: left;
}

.menu_option3 {
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: right;
}
</style>

<body>

<header>
<nav>

<div class="menu_bar">

<ul class="menu_items">
<li class="menu_logo"><a href="#"><img src="images/logo.gif"></a></li>
<li class="menu_option1"><a href="#"><img src="images/option1.gif"></a></li>
<li class="menu_option2"><a href="#"><img src="images/option2.gif"></a></li>
<li class="menu_option3"><a href="#"><img src="images/option3.gif"></a></li>
</ul>

</div>

</nav>
</header>

</body>
```

Comment: Percentage heights are based off of width.  Outside of using Viewport units, I don't see a way around that.  Not with pure CSS anyways.  http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Vertically aligning is also solved easily with a specific height, simply make the line-height match the height of the navbar.

Comment: So, basically, I have to do height: 50px and width: 100% instead of height: 15% and width: 100%? I suspected that was the case since it was the only thing I could get to work the way I want.

The downside is that the rest of the site is percentage heights and widths so they resize with the viewport. The navigation won't do the same. (I do have responsive layouts for important checkpoints.)

Comment: One caveat of the 100% height trick is that every parent element has to have some percentage height all the way up the stack to the body element.  If your navbar has a wrapping element, it too needs to have height: 15%;.  Then your UL's, LI's and A's should all have height: 15%;.

Comment: Even still, though, Michael, I won't be able to use vertical-align because it only is applicable to inline elements. Right? I'd have to use a table instead of divs.

Comment: Don't use a table, use display: table; and display: table-cell;  

You could also experiment with display: inline-block.  Which leaves the element to behave like a block level element with inline properties.  Vertical-align will work with inline-block.  Or again, using line-height to match the height of your div should vertically center your text in all cases also.

Comment: Michael, you answered my question. I'm not sure how to mark it as the answer.